# Assertion with a command

Tags: python, assert, assertion

Is there a way to pass a function into the string portion of an 'assert' statement like below? If not, are there any keywords in which I can do so?

```
f=5  
def something():
    assert f!=5, do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement for this:

```
f = 5
def something():
    if f!= 5:
        do_something_else()
```

Comment: I know i can use an if-else statement but I wanted a more efficient method for multiple conditions

Answer (score 1):

`assert` is used for Testing Warnings and you shouldn't rely on it for executing a block of codes.
[official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a function call in an `assert` statement just as you showed.  The function doesn't even have to return a string.  Python will try to put out a readable representation of whatever the function returns, including `None`.

The function will only be called if the condition after `assert` is false.